# Does the giant atx 2 2017 model have quick release wheels or thru axle wheels?

Tags: wheels, fork, quick-release, through-axle, giant

Just wanna know if the giant atx 2 has quick release wheels or thru axle

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lack of effort on the part of OP.

Answer (score 4):

It has a regular old quick release.

The bike is way too low end to have a thru axle.

You can see from pictures of the bike that it has dropouts in the fork and rear triangle, so the wheels are inserted in vertically. A thru axle does not have dropouts -- the axle has to go through the fork/frame. The wheel cannot be pulled vertically out from the frame.

Comment: Is there a way to convert it to a thru axle?

Comment: No. The bike has to be designed for it.